# What sort of antenna would use a bicone or lozenge-like arrangement of vertical wires?

Tags: antenna-theory, vertical-antenna

In another QA here, there's a picture of an antenna I identified as a "discone": [What are these antennas used for?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12978/what-are-these-antennas-used-for/12982)

One commenter noticed that antenna was actually a "Discone, but no disc, just the cone..." so I gave it a second look:

[image: View of antenna in question near Heidmoosstrasse]

Sure enough, no "disc". But now I don't even see "the cone" either!

There seem to be two things going on around this mast:

- Wires going from the mast to the ground. I count two sets of four such wires. These wires have a number of "bumps" on them. Probably guy wires to support the tower; with the bumps being insulators which split them up electrically so they don't mess with the pattern as much?
- Some eight or ten wires all around, running from the top of the mast, passing over a hoop halfway down the mast, and then gathering again at the bottom of the mast. These must be the active elements?

Unlike a discone, which is derived from a [biconical antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconical_antenna) where two cones meet at their point, this antenna seems to be shaped more like a geometric [bicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicone) where two cones are joined base-to-base instead.

What type of antenna — or, antenna *array* — is this?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discone_antenna

Comment: After I wrote this question, I noticed more details about the antenna shape but was still stuck on my "discone" impression. As a result the question ended up a muddled mess. I've now ± completely reworded this question to ask about the actual antenna arrangement pictured.

Comment: [*Lozenge*](https://www.google.com/search?q=lozenge) has more than one definition in the dictionary. You mean "diamond shaped", but by far the most common is *throat lozenge*, a medicine. I suggest you change *lozenge* to *diamond* to clarify the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a conical monopole antenna, as described by E.W. Pappenfus,  WB6LOH, in [*QST* for November 1966](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/qst/conical-monopole-antenna-november-1966-qst.htm). Antennas of the size order shown in the OP are probably for use from 4MHz and higher in the medium-wave band.

Paul Lee, N6PL, describes the "discage" in, "[The Amateur Radio Vertical Antenna Handbook](https://www.universal-radio.com/catalog/books/0043.html)" , which could explain the "disk" one may observe atop such antennas. 
The top disk is fed separately against the wire cage to provide improved coverage of the shortwave frequencies.

Comment: Thanks, I'm seeing some variation within "conical monopole" designs but I think that must be the correct term. I found https://www.flickr.com/photos/ssave/6947932920 where the poster elaborates: "a conical monopole is a 'fat' monopole which increases the bandwidth of frequencies that can be used with the antenna."